# angular-meteor Error: The package @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: angular-meteor

I wanted to give a try to Node+Angular. I am trying to follow [this](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping) tutorial.

On running the following command, I got a lot of errors.

```
meteor npm install --save angular2-meteor @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
```

I got a lot of warnings, but it's mentioned in the blogpost that I may get errors but they don't matter, but I'm also getting a lot of errors.

The warnings are:

```
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 included from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2 included from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2 included from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
```

Along with these warnings(these aren't ALL the warnings).

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/Users/vimarshchaturvedi/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.3_1.rkx5ga++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "angular2-meteor" "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic"
npm ERR! node v0.10.45
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2-meteor@0.5.5 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     ./npm-debug.log
```

I'm not sure what to do now. 
Further, I don't clearly understand if I can use NPM in Meteor w/o using Meteor.